# ¿Por que se debe colocar **kwars y super(LoginScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs) para que el codigo funcione?

Tags: python, class, kivy

```py
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.label import Label  
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):  
    def __init__(self,**kwargs): 
        super(LoginScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2 
        self.add_widget(Label(text='UserName')) 
        self.username=TextInput(multiline=False) 
        self.add_widget(self.username) 
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password')) 
        self.password=TextInput(password=True,multiline=False) 
        self.add_widget(self.password) 

class MyApp(App):   
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Puedes encontrar la respuesta en el Tutorial de Python: [4.7.2. Palabras claves como argumentos](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). Lectura recomendada para aprender Python.

Comment: No pongas la pregunta en el título y después solo código en la pregunta. Pon un título más corto, describe el problema dentro de la pregunta y haz la pregunta dentro.